# Tag synonyms unable to display right quantity of questions

Tags: bug, tagging, tag-management

I'm new here and I've just found a small bug in tag synonyms. This bug appears in both main and meta Math Stackexchange.

Some tags have synonyms, such as, in Math Stackexchange, tag [span](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/span) is a synonym for tag [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra), and [counting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting) is a synonym for [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics). The tag synonyms seems don't display the right quantity of questions. For example, tag [counting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting) displays "0 questions" in the [tag filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags) while displays "49.6k questions" when hovering. The same bug also appears in Meta Stack Exchange, such as tag [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) as a synonym for tag [comment](/questions/tagged/comment).

I don't know this bug appears in other Stackexchange sites or is mentioned before. I wish the moderator to pay attention and reply to my question.

Comment: Some related posts on [meta.se]: [Show total number of questions in synonym group at all occasions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262280),
[Why don't tag synonyms count towards the tag questions count? (+Bug?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325968),
[Display the number of question for tag synonyms in the tag search, or indicate it is a tag synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347851)